# Should I store my shopping cart in DB or Session array?

Tags: php, database, session, e-commerce

I'm still a student learning PHP at the moment, and since I didn't find any answers that would satisfy me (although if its already answered feel free to link it) I came here. I'm making an e-commerce website for my final project at school, and couldn't decide if its better to store the cart in a session array or in database? Right now I store it at a database, identifying it with session_id(), (not user id because It's not necessary to log in to put items in the cart). But I realized, It will stuck in the database if the user doesn't continue to the checkout page and just leaves the site forever. At the checkout page I'm querying the cart table and get the datas from it, so I could theoretically use a session array, but It's mutch more convenient for me to use a database. I saw answers like one should store the cart in a session array and store that in the databse, but then I don't rly know how this problem would solve. Is there any way to delete stuff from the cart table after some time? What's the best practice? (It's just a school project so its running on localhost if thats important, and as long as it works no one cares how I made it, but im still curious).

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: This is probably more opinion-based, because carts can be stored both ways. If you're concerned about carts stored forever in the database, you can set up an automated script that will delete any cart older than a certain time.

Comment: Both are valid solutions but they solve different things (keep cart handy while browsing / allow you continue shopping another day). Your current code combines the drawbacks of both because you have persistent information that becomes unusable after a short time ("Right now I store it at a database, identifying it with session_id()").